# Trying to understand Classes

Tags: class

I have searched about class and int but I still don't understand.

I have seen this code online I want to understand it

```
class Motor { 

  int enablePin;
  int directionPin1;
  int directionPin2;
  public: 

  //Method to define the motor pins
  Motor(int ENPin,int dPin1,int dPin2){
    enablePin = ENPin;
    directionPin1 = dPin1;
    directionPin2 = dPin2;
};
```

Comment: here is an interactive web page that may help ... http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: which part are you having problems with?

Answer (score 4):

```
class Motor {
```

This says to start defining a class. A class is like a "container" that holds both data and functions (methods). After defining the class, it becomes like a new variable type that you can declare multiple instances of.

```
  int enablePin;
  int directionPin1;
  int directionPin2;
```

These define the 3 integer variables (int=integer; whole numbers like 2, 3, 1000, -5, etc.) that belong to the class and have the identifiers given (`enablePin`, etc.) Since not otherwise specified, these variables are *private*, meaning that only other functions **in** the class can access them. Other parts of the program are not allowed to access these variables.

```
public:
```

This means that the following definitions *are* accessible by parts of the program that exist outside the class.

```
Motor(int ENPin,int dPin1,int dPin2) {
  enablePin = ENPin;
  directionPin1 = dPin1;
  directionPin2 = dPin2;
}
```

This defines the only "member function" in this class and because it shares the same name as the class (`Motor`), it is called a "Constructor", and allows you to pass arguments to an object created from the class -- in this case, if you declare an object of class `Motor` by `myMotor = Motor(1, 2, 3);`, the constructor is called with parameters `1`, `2`, and `3`. This constructor happens to just set the private variables to be the same as the arguments passed in.

But... All of this is basic C++, so a book or course on C++ programming would be better in-depth resource to understand this.

The code snippet also is incorrect because it has unbalanced curly-braces -- there is one to open the definition of the class and one to open the definition of the constructor, but only one closing brace.